Method level security using SpEL
I read from Spring documentation that to enable dynamic method level meta annotations I need to configure a class called AnnotationTemplateExpressionDefaults.
I have done that here
@Bean
public AnnotationTemplateExpressionDefaults annotationTemplateExpressionDefaults(){
    return new AnnotationTemplateExpressionDefaults();
}

I then configured an annotation called HasAnyRole:
@Target({ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@PreAuthorize(value = "hasAnyRole({roles})")
public @interface HasAnyRole {

    String[] roles();
}

Then I annotated a method with HasAnyRole and passed the following roles
@PostMapping("/create")
@HasAnyRole(roles = {"'MANAGING_DIRECTOR'","'OPERATIONS_MANAGER'","'PROJECT_MANAGER'"})
public ResponseEntity<APIResponse> createProject(@Valid @RequestBody ProjectCreationRequest projectCreationRequest)
        throws ProjectNotCreatedException{
    return projectService.generateProjectCreationRequest(projectCreationRequest);
}

When I called this method I got the error:
Failed to evaluate expression 'hasAnyRole({roles})'"

But on further research I am finding out that this does not work with PreAuthorize and I will need to either use AOP or create custom bean that I can use to resolve the annotation HasAnyRole.
My question is what am I doing wrong because I followed the documentation and still did not get the desired result

What happens when you add the static modifier to the method that creates the AnnotationTemplateExpressionDefaults bean?

I’ve tried that and got the same error. I read that the because the roles is an array SpEL does not have the ablility to map collections at runtime and can only map single values because HasRole() method having just a single role worked out

AnnotationTemplateExpressionDefaults is only available since spring-security 6.4.
In addition,if you use spring boot,you can direct use spring boot 3.4.1.

Yes I have this imported from spring security 6.4 but I still had to update the springboot version to 3.4.1

Yes，beacuse it base on spring 6.2

I changed the Spring Boot version to 3.4.1 in my pom.xml file and the issue was resolved. Just having the AnnotationTemplateExpressionDefaults imported through Spring Security 6.4 did not resolve the issue until the Spring Boot version was changed.
